# Perform Loop Based on Groupings of Rows

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, foreach

this is my first time posting!

I have a data set similar to
[image: this]

Essentially there is data split into three columns (ID, Record, and Variable). For each "group" (based on the ID they share), I need to be able to reset the order of the records so that 4 and 5 come last in the "group." Then, the function would be able to go to the next one. Finally, I would expect a result like
[image: this]

A few key points:

1. I cannot use sorting/filtering because none of the IDs/Records/Variables in the true data set are in numeric order
2. Cannot split it out into different sheets/macros, because there are thousands of unique IDs.

Tried to work through this, but have some issues with my code doing nothing (below). Any ideas?

```
Sub GrpUpdate()

Dim f As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim last As Long

grpOne = "4"
grpTwo = "5"
i = 2
f = i
last = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Range("A" & f).Value, after:=Range("A" & f), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

For f = i To last

    If f = last Then
        i = last + 1
        f = i
        last = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Range("A" & f).Value, after:=Range("A" & f), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        
    ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(grpOne, "B" & f & ":" & "B" & last, 0)) And Not IsError(Application.Match(grpTwo, "B" & f & ":" & "B" & last, 0)) Then
        Rows(Range("B" & f & ":" & "B" & last).Find(what:=grpOne, after:=Range("B" & f), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row).Cut
        Rows(last).Insert
        Rows(Range("B" & f & ":" & "B" & last).Find(what:=grpTwo, after:=Range("B" & f), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row).Cut
        Rows(last).Insert
        
    ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(grpOne, "B" & f & ":" & "B" & last, 0)) Then
        Rows(Range("B" & f & ":" & "B" & last).Find(what:=grpOne, after:=Range("B" & f), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row).Cut
        Rows(last).Insert
        
    ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(grpTwo, "B" & f & ":" & "B" & last, 0)) Then
        Rows(Range("B" & f & ":" & "B" & last).Find(what:=grpTwo, after:=Range("B" & f), searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row).Cut
        Rows(last).Insert
        
    End If

Next f

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not sorting the columns (Data -> Sort)? Or am my misunderstanding what you want to do?

Comment: More details required: 1) are the rows for each ID value in consecutive rows, or can they be separated by other IDs? 2)Are Record and Variable always the same value? 3) Can there be values of Record (or Variable) greater then 5? 4) Is the real data numeric, like in your sample?

Comment: Sorting would work fine on your sample data set to produce your output set. It would be helpful for you to supply a sample data set (and result set) where sorting doesn't work, as you write.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the comments.

Rows for each ID are not consecutive, record and variable are not always the same, and the data is always numeric, but not as simple as this. That's why sorting wouldn't work for the true data set.

Thank you for the feedback on providing a more realistic example set. My issue was that I hadn't had the chance to put it more together due to the complexity of the true data (which I can't share due to it having private information).

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub GrpUpdate()
    Dim f As Range, first As Long, last As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, numRows As Long, addrGroups As String, arrLast, g
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet      'or whatever
    first = 2                 'start here
    
    arrLast = Array("4", "5") 'items which (if present) should be last for each Id, in order
    
    Do While Len(ws.Cells(first, "A").Value) > 0
        
        With ws.Cells(first, "A") 'find the last value
            last = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:=.Value, after:=.Cells(1), _
                                searchdirection:=xlPrevious, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        End With
        numRows = 1 + (last - first)
        
        If numRows > 1 Then 'ignore single rows
            'Using the range address because we're cutting rows which can be
            '   weird with Range references....
            addrGroups = ws.Cells(first, "B").Resize(numRows).Address 'address for the "group" range
            For Each g In arrLast   'loop items to be ordered last
                Set f = ws.Range(addrGroups).Find(what:=g, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    f.EntireRow.Cut 'move the found row to the end of the group
                    ws.Rows(last + 1).Insert
                End If
            Next g
        End If           '>1 row    
        first = last + 1 'next Id
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I may follow-up, but this seems to work perfectly!